# Meteor performance: Multiple subscriptions vs only 1 performance

Tags: javascript, meteor

Morning everyone!

I have a design question that I haven't managed to find an answer to and maybe more knowledgeable people could give me some input.

I'm writing an app that requires small amounts of data from multiple sources. At the moment it's written with template level subscriptions, each one subscribing to data it needs (Each subscription returns about 20-25 small documents max)

Is this the most efficient way from a performance perspective? Or would one subscription returning all the necessary cursors at once work better?

Thank you

Comment: How is it loaded? Does it use AJAX or is it all loaded by default?

Comment: They are reactive subscriptions to the database (No AJAX) . This is a Meteor app by the way I forgot to mention

Comment: Ok, update your question details ;)

Comment: @CarlosB. yes it's good way, It depends if your whole application depends on it and you redirect a lot to different pages maybe it makes sense to subscribe to the documents on home template so those subscription don't stop.  Or you can look into caching the documents. But it's actually fine to have multiple subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks Mark. That leads me to another question that I've been trying to figure out. All these little templates are presented at once. I want to load a "loading" template whilst all the subscriptions are ready. I know I can use {{#Template.subscriptionsReady}}, but that only seems to apply to the parent template. I'm assuming there's no built in way to do this but waiting for all the child templates?

Comment: do you want to show a loading template for every little template or globally until all subscriptions from all little templates are ready?

Comment: A global one until everything is ready to view so to speak :)